# Geodatabase feature to KMZ - display issue with stacked lines

Tags: arcgis-desktop, google-earth, kmz

I am working with a line feature in ArcGIS. My end product is a KMZ for use in Google Earth. However, there are lines that are stacked on top of each other in the feature. When I convert my feature to a KMZ only one feature is clickable in Google Earth, meaning clicking on stacked lines only displays the attributes of the topmost line. Is there any sort of method to deal with stacked lines? I know that point features that are stacked expand when you click on them to display all stacked points, but this is not a feature with lines apparently.

Comment: Can you please edit your question to reflect what version of ArcGIS you are using? Welcome to GIS.SE!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is a pure GE limitation - and I am not aware of a direct way to force GE to spread the lines (that would be nice, though).

Assuming that feature does not in fact exist - there are two options I can think of.

1. Set different heights based on what you want to have priority (clamp the less important features to the ground and set a height of a few meters for the feature that you want to see).
2. If you really want all of the data to be visible directly in GE - combine the features in ArcMap first and then just send out the geometry once, instead of your coincident geometries with different attributes.